# suphp how disable ls /

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Using suphp, I set a php.ini to every virtual host. In php.ini I also setted:

```
open_basedir = /home/site1
```

php script runs, but if I ve a script with ls / I can see whole root directory.

How can disable this hole security?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site1
ServerAlias www.site1.com

DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
DocumentRoot /home/site1/

suPHP_Engine on
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php

# THIS READ php.ini
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/site1/

<Directory /home/site1/>

Options -Includes -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI -MultiViews
AllowOverride none
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the execution of external binaries to get rid of this behavior.

**UPDATE** you can do it this way, you have to edit your php.ini

```
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,
        system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,
        curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

(I included line breaks for clarity.)

This is the original URL: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/